# Scrapy use case - new links only

Tags: python, scrapy

At a high level - I think I'm trying to use the Scrapy framework like a scraping library.

My use case is, I have a webpage with links to meeting minutes I'd like to scrape, as time passes, more links to meeting minutes are added.

My plan was to use a regular spider to scrape the links to meeting minutes, and pipeline/`CsvItemExporter` the list of links to a CSV.

Regular Spider 1 - webpage with links to meeting minutes I'd like to scrape, exports to csv:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "easthamptontown-links"

custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'themis.pipelines.ThemisPipeline': 400
    }
}

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://easthamptontown.iqm2.com/Citizens/Calendar.aspx?From=1/1/1900&To=12/31/9999',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    rowtops = response.xpath('//div[@class="RowTop"]')
    for meeting in rowtops:
        yield {
            'meeting': meeting.css("a[href*='Detail_Meeting']").get(),
            'files': meeting.css("a[href*='FileView']").getall(),
        }
```

Pipeline 1

```
class ThemisPipeline:
def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s.csv' % spider.name, 'wb')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    file_output = {}
    _item = ItemAdapter(item).asdict()
    if len(_item['files']) > 0:
        for filelink in _item['files']:
            parser = MyHTMLParser()
            parser.feed(filelink)
            file_output['filelink'] = parser.lsHref
            file_output['filetype'] = parser.lsData
            parser.feed(_item['meeting'])
            file_output['meetinglink'] = parser.lsHref
            file_output['meetingtitle'] = parser.lsTitle
            file_output['meetingdate'] = parser.lsData.strip()
            self.exporter.export_item(file_output)
    else:
        DropItem(item)
    return item
```

A CsvReader()/list comprehension feeds the links from the CSV to a second regular spider in `start_urls`, which, using the links, scrapes the meeting minutes and pipeline/CsvItemExporter to a `.txt` file named for the link, eg `meeting123.txt`.

The second time I run the first scraper, compare to the links in the new csv to the original csv, scrape the meeting minutes in links in the new csv but not the original csv
pipeline/`CsvItemExporter` to a `.txt` file named for the link, eg `meeting124.txt`.

My immediate problem is that passing the scraped minutes link to the pipeline to name the file after the minutes link is harder than I would have guessed - the framework doesn't seem to be for this.

regular spider 2 - scrapes meeting minutes from URLs supplied from a CSV:

```
class ASpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "town-text"

custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'themis.pipelines.MinutesPipeline': 400
    }
}

meetings = csvreader('./town-links.csv')
# don't override start_requests, default scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
start_urls = ['http://http://easthamptontown.iqm2.com/Citizens/' + meeting['filelink'] \
              for meeting in meetings \
              if 'Zoning' in meeting['meetingtitle'] and \
              'Regular Meeting' in meeting['meetingtitle'] and \
              meeting['filetype'] == 'Minutes']

def parse(self, response):
    for element in response.xpath('//div[@id="Content"]/div/*'):
        yield {
            'line': element.xpath('.//text()').getall(),
        }
```

pipeline:

```
class MinutesPipeline:
def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    file = open('%s.txt' % spider.name, 'wb')
    self.files[spider] = file
    self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    file = self.files.pop(spider)
    file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    _item = ItemAdapter(item).asdict()
    self.exporter.export_item(_item)
    return item
```

I'd like to be able to pass the particular URL whose `html` I am scraping, `meeting['filelink']`, - to the CSV filename for the items. I tried changing `scrapy.Spider` to `CrawlSpider` to attempt to use `parse_start_url()` but the selector did not return any data using `CrawlSpider`.

Any thoughts on design for this use case unique to the Scrapy framework would be appreciated.

Comment: What seems to be going wrong in your original attempts at solving this?   Please create a [mre]

Comment: Why is it that you want to use 2 spiders?  And where is the code for the second spider?

Comment: I used two spiders because I wanted to store the list of links I scraped - to compare to the list the next time I scraped - and then only pass on the new links - is there a better way?

Comment: Better is subjective, but you could certainly do it using just one spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `url` as the filename all you need to do is pass the url with the item, and create a new file with said filename and export it.

for example:

In your parse method add a url field to the dictionary and add the `response.url` as it's value.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for element in response.xpath('//div[@id="Content"]/div/*'):
        yield {
            'line': element.xpath('.//text()').getall(),
            'url': response.url
        }
```

Then in your pipeline:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    url = item["url"]
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    exporter = CsvItemExporter(filename)
    text = item["text"]
    ... do text formatting if needed
    ...  export to text to file
    raise DropItem
```